# Xcode print keys and values of Dictionary

Tags: swift2, xcode7

Print description in Xcode 7 is giving memory addresses similar to below. Tried all the options, but getting output like this.

```
▿ 3 elements
  ▿ [0] : 2 elements
    - .0 : Output
    ▿ .1 : 3 elements
      ▿ [0] : 2 elements
        - .0 : type
        - .1 : Output2 { ... }
      ▿ [1] : 2 elements
        - .0 : version
        - .1 : 1.0
      ▿ [2] : 2 elements
        - .0 : content
        ▿ .1 : 2 elements
```

How can I instead print the exact values of a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this test dictionary:

```
let dict:Dictionary = ["key1": "value1", "key2": 42, "keyForColor": UIColor.redColor()]
```

Then I used `po dict` and get the result you described:

```
po dict
▿ 3 elements
  ▿ [0] : 2 elements
    - .0 : "key1"
    - .1 : value1
  ▿ [1] : 2 elements
    - .0 : "keyForColor"
  ▿ [2] : 2 elements
    - .0 : "key2"
```

When you use `po dict.description`, you get this:

```
po dict.description
"[\"key1\": value1, \"keyForColor\": UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1, \"key2\": 42]"
```

Comment: compared to printing Dictionaries in Xcode 6, this is unreadable. Even with `po dict.description`. Is there no workaround?

Comment: @user1463853 i don't have Xcode6. what do you need as 'acceptable' print out?. which information is missing?

Comment: @user1463853 just use repl dump(dict) to better explore the same dict

Answer (score 6):

Try with [CFShow](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFShow):

> Prints a description of a Core Foundation object to stderr.

```
 po CFShow(dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<command-name>'.
(lldb) repl dump(dict)
▿ 3 key/value pairs
  ▿ [0]: (2 elements)
    - .0: key1
    ▿ .1: Swift._NSContiguousString #0
      ▿ super: Swift._SwiftNativeNSString
        ▿ super: value1
          ▿ NSString: value1
            - NSObject: value1
      ▿ _core: Swift._StringCore
        ▿ _baseAddress: Swift.COpaquePointer
          - _rawValue: (Opaque Value)
        - _countAndFlags: 6
        - _owner: nil
  ▿ [1]: (2 elements)
    - .0: keyForColor
    ▿ .1: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1 #1
      ▿ UIDeviceRGBColor: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1
        ▿ UIColor: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1
          - NSObject: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1
  ▿ [2]: (2 elements)
    - .0: key2
    ▿ .1: 42 #2
      ▿ NSNumber: 42
        ▿ NSValue: 42
          - NSObject: 42
([String : NSObject]) $R1 = 3 key/value pairs {
  [0] = (key = "key1", value = "value1")
  [1] = (key = "keyForColor", value = 0x00007f9c42d3aab0)
  [2] = (key = "key2", value = Int64(42))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up on @user3441734, you can simply get the last part by using `p` instead of `po`:

```
(lldb) p dict
([String : NSObject]) $R1 = 3 key/value pairs {
  [0] = (key = "key1", value = "value1")
  [1] = (key = "keyForColor", value = 0x00007f9c42d3aab0)
  [2] = (key = "key2", value = Int64(42))
}
```

If this doesn't suit your needs, you could always write an extension of Dictionary and build a custom description, something in the line of:

```
extension Dictionary {

  var fancyDescription: String {
      var description = ""
      for (key, value) in self {
          description += "\(key) : \(value), "
      }  
      return "{ \(description) }"
  }
}
```

and use it with `po dict.fancyDescription`