# What exactly does debugger print when you are printing a dictionary?

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, dictionary

I have a dictionary of type `[String : NSTimer]`.
When I use a breakpoint to print it in the **console**, I get the following results:

```
▿ 2 elements // Does this means 2 key-value pairs?
  ▿ [0] : 2 elements // What does this 2 element mean here?
    - .0 : "https://github.jack.com" // what does .0 mean here?
  ▿ [1] : 2 elements
    - .0 : "https://github.john.com"
```

However if I use the **Variables view** from Xcode I can see the value of the object as :

```
[0] (key: String, value: NSTimer)   
key String  "https://github.jack.com"   
value   NSTimer 0x00006100001726c0
[1] (key: String, value: NSTimer)   
key String  "https://github.john.com"   
value   NSTimer 0x00006000001756c0 // contrary to console, value is shown
```

Is this a bug? Or this is the intended behavior when printing a dictionary? If so why is that way?

Also is the [0], [1] just for the sake of differentiating between the keys? Because dictionaries have no order. right?

<sub>PS I have also wrote some questions inside my code</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode 7 print keys and values of Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936686/xcode-7-print-keys-and-values-of-dictionary)

Comment: @ThomasWeller That Question and its answers are only slightly similar. Barely answering anything of my question. I'm trying to understand what the console is doing and that question doesn't address it

Comment: Is it a bug? No. Is it intended? Yes. Why is it so? Because it was designed like that. Ask the developers. Is the 0,1 for the sake of differentiating? Yes. Dictionaries have no order? Yes.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm still trying to make sense of : **1)** why it was designed like that. I'm sure there is a good semantic reason that we don't know of. We can many many other questions from them, but not a good answer **2)** Am I right to be confused about seeing 0,1 in something that isn't ordered? Is that again good design or bad design?

Comment: @Honey I don't agree that it's not a duplicate. It _is_ a duplicate. If you look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32936755/341994 he is showing exactly the same problem you're showing, namely that the keys are displayed but not the values (when the values are objects).

Comment: Have you read my question? I have 5 questions asked in my question, PDK answered them all. The other question only addressed *Is this a bug? Or this is the intended behavior when printing a dictionary? If so why is that way?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, looks like you're not using the latest (stable) Xcode, because my Xcode (Version 8.1, 8B62) says:

> Swift Compiler Error: 'NSTimer' has been renamed to 'Timer'

This hideous example does show "normal" output though:

```
let timerA = Timer(timeInterval: 123, repeats: false, block: { _ in })
let timerB = Timer(timeInterval: 123, repeats: false, block: { _ in })
let soExample: [String:Timer] = ["a":timerA, "b":timerB]
print(soExample)
dump(soExample)
```

Shows in the Console:

```
// ["b": <__NSCFTimer: 0x6000001738c0>, "a": <__NSCFTimer: 0x600000173440>]
// ▿ 2 key/value pairs
//   ▿ (2 elements)
//     - .0: "b"
//     - .1: <__NSCFTimer: 0x600000169180> #0
//       - super: NSTimer
//         - super: NSObject
//   ▿ (2 elements)
//     - .0: "a"
//     - .1: <__NSCFTimer: 0x600000169240> #1
//       - super: NSTimer
//         - super: NSObject
```

About the debug print:

Yes, you should see "2 key-value pairs".

Then a tuple of 2 elements: (key, value) …where `.0` is shorthand for the first tuple element. (see [The Swift Programming Language: Tuples](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID329))

Indeed, [dictionaries have no ordering](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html).

> Dictionaries are unordered collections of key-value associations.

…so I agree with you that in the Variables view in Xcode, with its [0] and [1], can confuse newcomers—as you can see, the print outs in the Console don't confuse. ;-)

Comment: I'm using Xcode 8 + Swift 2.3 **1)** So your Xcode is actually printing the key and value **together**?  So this is a bug right? **2)** So you mean every dictionary is written using tuples? And just to be sure you pasted from the console *not* from the Variables view right?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. So for it's not printing the value, is that a bug?

Comment: 1) the output you see (minus the slashes) is the result from the statements `print` & `dump`; as you can see, `dump` is more verbose. 2) from the SDK inside the `struct Dictionary` a dictionary key-value element =
_The element type of a dictionary: a **tuple** containing an individual key-value pair._

Comment: It might be a bug, but since on my side it looks fine: without looking into it further, it seems related to Swift 2. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32936755/3419541 Same symptoms.